# Enrolling my application to crash reporter, and get dumps on user consent

Tags: macos, ios, crash

I know that when an application crashes on a user's device, macOS (or iOS) can collect a crash report.

Users have the option to share these crash reports with Apple, and if the app is distributed through the Mac App Store, developers can access aggregated crash reports via App Store Connect.

If my application doesn't distributed through apple store and it's provided by other independent means, is there a way to get the crash reports from Apple ?

Basically, i'd like to refrain from developing a mechanism that monitor and collect crashes. The question is whether this is possible outside AppStore